# Fabric.JS not working with Promises or callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, fabricjs

So I'm using a Node.JS/NPM library called `fabric.js` **(Node.JS, not for the browser)** that works is an odd way.

```
//Make a new Canvas object (`fabric.createCanvasForNode` is not a constructor)
var canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, {width: 200, height: 200})

  //Make a new Rectangle
  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    fill: "red"
  })

//Put the Rectangle on the Canvas
canvas.add(rect)

//Save the image as a PNG
canvas.createPNGStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + "/output.png"))
```

The only issue is that `canvas.add()` is a function that **should** return a Promise, but doesn't. It's a function that isn't instantaneous, but doesn't already work with Promises (`canvas.add(...).then() is not a function`). The next thing I tried was callbacks. I tried:

```
canvas.add(rect, function (err, canvas) {
  console.log("working")
})
```

along with

```
canvas.add(rect, function () {
  console.log("working")
})
```

but both errored with:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\fabric\dist\fabric.js:3696
            obj._set("canvas", this);
                ^

TypeError: obj._set is not a function
    at klass._onObjectAdded (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\fabric\dist\fabric.js:3696:17)
    at klass.add (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\fabric\dist\fabric.js:152:22)
    at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\index.js:41:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Client.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:330:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:293:17)
    at WebSocketClient.internalOnMessage (C:\Users\me\Documents\my project\node_modules\uws\uws.js:103:17)
```

So what do I do? Am I doing something wrong with the way I'm using Promises and/or callbacks? Does fabric simply not support them? What's a workaround for this?

Comment: How do you know that it "*should return a Promise*"?

Comment: @Bergi because the code above wouldn't render the rectangle^^ if I were to setTimeout and then output the file, it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.StaticCanvas.html#add) the method `fabric.StaticCanvas.add` do not use of either `Promise` nor `Callback`.

---

[image]

Comment: So then how can I solve the issue with the code I shared in the question not rendering the rectangle unless theres a setTimeout before outputting the file?

Comment: Try to add `canvas.requestRenderAll()` or `canvas.renderAll();` before to create the stream